# Apply rule of three in dplyr

Tags: r, dplyr

I want to apply the rule of three to find an unknown number. An example of rule of three is the following:

If I have 8 litres of paint for 2 bedrooms, how many litres of paint would I need for 5 bedrooms?

Below is the table I am working on:

| group | sub_group | n | ttl_amt |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| A | control | 1702 | 4791 |
| A | target | 32637 | 102143 |
| B | target | 12355 | 53640 |
| C | control | 1012 | 2943 |
| C | target | 19514 | 56017 |

The sub_group variable has only either control or target. My goal is to add a new variable called ttl_amt_adjusted, which is calculated as the following:
for each group, take the n of sub_group target, multiply it by ttl_amt of sub_group control, and then divide it by n of sub_group control. So for the first row, ttl_amt_adjusted would result in: 32637*4791/1702=91870.66

Desired result should be like the following:

| group | sub_group | n | ttl_amt | ttl_amt_adjusted |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| A | control | 1702 | 4791 | 91870.66 |
| A | target | 32637 | 102143 | 102143 |
| B | target | 12355 | 53640 | 53640 |
| C | control | 1012 | 2943 | 56748.72 |
| C | target | 19514 | 56017 | 56017 |

Note1: some groups have only target as sub_group (third row), and for these, ttl_amt_adjusted should be equal to ttl_amt.

Note2: ttl_amt_adjusted for sub_group target should just be equal to ttl_amt

Here is the code I tried with dplyr:

```
df%>%
  group_by(group)%>%
  arrange(group,sub_group)%>%
  mutate(ttl_amt_adjusted=lag(n,default=last(n))*lead(ttl_amt,default=first(ttl_amt))/lead(n,default=first(n)))
```

However, this is not showing the correct result.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is the solution I found to this:

```
df%>%
  group_by(group)%>%
  arrange(group,sub_group)%>%
  mutate(ttl_adjusted=last(n)*first(ttl_amt)/first(n),
         ttl_adjusted=case_when(sub_group=="TG"~ttl_amt,TRUE~ttl_adjusted))
```